# asp.net web application and c# code to control the repeaters.

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, controller

I have been trying to write c# code in .cs file to control the repeaters. 
I donot know how to use entity model to get the data from table and execute using repeaters into categories to subcategories...

here is HTML cod :

```
           <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
               <ItemTemplate>
               <table>
          <tr>  
          <td style="height:50px">
                    <a href="Home.aspx?id=1"> <asp:Label ID="lbl1" runat="server"> <%#Eval("ForumName") %> </asp:Label></a></td> 
         <td>  By : <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"> <%#Eval("CeatedBy") %></asp:Label></td>
         <td>  on  <asp:Label ID="lbl3" runat="server"> <%#Eval("DateCreated") %></asp:Label></td> <br /> <br /> </tr>
                      </table></ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>

           <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" >
               <ItemTemplate>
                   <table>
                       <tr>
                           <td> <asp:Label ID="lbl4" runat="server" selectcommand="SELECT [ThreadName] FROM [Threads]" > <%#Eval("ThreadName") %></asp:Label></td>
                       </tr>
                   </table>
               </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>

           <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ForumConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ThreadName] FROM [Threads]" ></asp:SqlDataSource>
           <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ForumConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ForumName], [CeatedBy], [DateCreated], [IsActive] FROM [Forum1]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I have to put the thread name below the particular forum...! and so i am not able to figure out the c# code for it by using entity model..!

awaiting for the solution..

thanks ,
Jay

Answer (score 0):

You want to use entity framework to bind your data against those repeaters in codebehind file ?

Comment: yes , just a function which can bring all particular categories and should display below respected main categories

Comment: Fallowing are some tutorials that will guide you to make you entity model

http://entityframeworktutorial.net/create-first-simple-EDM.aspx

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1

Once you are done with making model , then you have to make a List<T> of your category , and then get the Sub category of it based on your database relationship. Then only you have to do is bind that list to your repeaters.